# display blob image in jsp and servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I'm trying to display a image which comes from the database as a blob image.
this is my servlet code to display the image

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    Blob image = null;
    byte[] imgData = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/users", "root", "");

        stmt = con.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("select photo from details where name='" + name + "'");

        String imgLen = "";
        while (rs.next()) {
            imgLen = rs.getString(1);
        }
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("select photo from details where name='" + name + "'");
        if (rs.next()) {
            
            out.println("\n");
            out.println("Getting blob");
            Blob blob = rs.getBlob(1);
            out.println("Reading image");
            BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(blob.getBinaryStream());
            out.println("img = " + img);
            
    } catch (Exception e) {
        out.println("Unable To Display image");
        out.println("Image Display Error");
        return;
    } finally {
        try {
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            //con.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

but this code only give the details about the image, not the exact image. How can I display the real image?

Comment: it is better to path of image in database rather than image. Store your image on server(your machine's local disk) and store path of this image in db.It will be more fast

Comment: yes it works at any situation I have done it before :) but I wanna try this one too ;)